# How to do XSLT transformation utilising XML comments?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-lists

What XSLT will transform the following pattern of XML into the HTML output below?

```
<ELEMENT1>
  <!--
  Comment for element 2
  -->
  <ELEMENT2>
    <ELEMENT3>ABC</ELEMENT3>
  </ELEMENT2>
  <!--
  Comment for element 4
  -->
  <ELEMENT4>
    <ELEMENT5>0534564117</ELEMENT5>
    <!--
        Comment for element 6
    -->   
    <ELEMENT6>123456</ELEMENT6>
  </ELEMENT4>
</ELEMENT1>
```

**Output:**

> - ELEMENT1
>   - *Comment for Element
>       2*
>   - ELEMENT2
>     - ELEMENT3
>   - *Comment for Element 4*
>   - ELEMENT4
>     - ELEMENT5
>     - *Comment for Element 6*
>     - ELEMENT6

Comment: Please be careful of your terms / typos.  You just created a typo tag.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want a stylesheet with three templates.  One template matches the document root and emits the outer HTML structure, and recurs as usual on all child nodes.  It wraps everything else in an HTML unordered list.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head><title>Demo document</title></head>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

One template handles elements by emitting a list item containing the element type name.  If the element has children, it recurs on them, wrapping their output in a nested `ul` element.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:if test="node()">
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```

If you don't mind emitting an empty `ul` element (most browsers don't particularly care), you can do without the `xsl:if` surrounding the nested `ul`.

The third template matches comments and emits list items for them, wrapping the content of the comment in an `i` element.

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
  <li><i><xsl:value-of select="."/></i></li>
</xsl:template>
```

You may also want a template to deal with text nodes, if the default template for text nodes is not acceptable.

Comment: When I run the above templates I seem to get the data within the tags.  I was wanting to exclude the data and only have the tag names and the comments.

Comment: @CJ7 to exclude the text nodes you can either add a `<xsl:template match="text()"/>` to suppress printing of them or alternatively exclude them when recursing, by using `<xsl:apply-templates select="* | comment()"/>` (to select only elements and comment nodes, as node() includes text nodes as well).

Comment: @IanRoberts: how do I suppress the opening `<?xml` line?

Comment: The above combination of templates is causing the list to indent when it shouldn't.  The list keeps on indenting when the nodes are actually on the same layer in the XML.

Comment: @CJ7 `<xsl:output method="html"/>` should tell it that the output is HTML rather than XML.

Comment: I recommend you spend some time with a good tutorial introduction to XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you may be looking for is the xsl:comment instruction, which creates a comment in the output.